# sending any URL as a query param to an API

Tags: javascript, rest, api, jersey

So, recently I was trying to make a post(javascript ajax) request to a publicly exposed REST API with an URL as query param. Lets say the endpoint was `example.com/api/urls` and I was trying to make a post request to this endpoint, with an URL as query param like below

`example.com/api/urls/url=http://xyz.abc?a=sdffd&jkder`

now in the resource value that I am getting for the query param(url) is `http://xyz.abc?a=sdffd`, my requirement is to get the complete url, which is `http://xyz.abc?a=sdffd&jkder` .

Update:
There is always an option to send the URL through request body, but can we send it through query parameters.

Answer (score 0):

You need to percent-encode the ampersand in the URL.
The code is `%26`

Comment: There are tables online listing all the HTML entity codes, see http://www.ascii.cl/htmlcodes.htm

Answer (score 0):

Hello can you build an object for you parameters ? Like so ?

```
 var requestData = {
        url : 'http://xyz.abc?a=sdffd&jkder'
    };

    $.ajax({
        url: 'example.com/api/urls',
        type: 'POST',
        data: JSON.stringify(requestData),
        dataType: 'json',
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        error: function (xhr) {
            // do stuff on error
        },
        success: function (result) {                
            // do stuff on success
        },
        async: true,
        processData: false
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to URL encode the url string, its a good practice to URL encode any request parameter before sending to server to avoid decoding issues.

URLEncoder.encode() is present in Java.
Javascript should be similar library.